# How can i use the "where like" query for number value in AdonisJS query builder?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, backend, adonis.js

[image]

We can use the where like query in Adonis JS for String value like below

```
await ModelName.query()
  .where('descriptions', 'LIKE', "%somevalue%")
```

It is ok if descriptions is a string value, but not a numeric value.

```
await ModelName.query()
  .where('quantity', 'LIKE', "%somevalue%")
```

this gives me the error with `operator does not exist: numeric ~~ unknown`

So need to cast the type of value from number to string first.
Is there any recommendation for this?

Comment: It's very strange that you are searching numeric value with like operator. Are you sure you need that kind of functionality? .where('quantity', somevalue) will search exact number and if you for example want bigger numbers than 9000 you would write .query('qty', '>', 3). But to search numbers with like query?? Why would you need such functionality?

Comment: Because i wanna realise the search functionality in the backend.
Before we used the search feature of the frontend mui datatable, but now because the rows are very large like 100k in the db table, so we need to move the search function to the backend. Please check the screenshot of frontend muitable, is showing search results for qty.

Comment: If you really need this (and I dont think that searching numbers by similarity is useful at all) you will need to create one more column in that table, called quantity_string or something and make it varchar. Than use that column for search.

Answer (score 0):

```
await ModelName.query().whereRaw("quantity::TEXT like '%somevalue%'")
```

It'd be something like this